# SSIS: SQLCMD inside Execute Process Task

Tags: ssis, etl, sqlcmd

I am trying to run a SQLCMD inside an Execute Process Task in SSIS.

My Task is setup as such:

Executable:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE
```

Arguments:

```
-S XXXXXXXXX -d XXXXXXXXX -E -s, -W -Q "SELECT * FROM DATABASE.SCHEMA.TABLENAME" | findstr /V /C:"-" /B  > "OUTPUT\PATH\FileName.csv"
```

My ultimate goal is to have the DB table dynamic in a for each loop but for now I will settle for just having an isolated task run.

The error I'm receiving: `The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".`

I understand it's a very generic error that could mean a variety of things but I'm hoping someone can see something inherently wrong with my setup OR explain how I can produce more logging.

I should mention that I am able to run this command just fine in a command prompt.

I appreciate any guidance. Thanks.